# Scala Apache Spark and dynamic column list inside of DataFrame select method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Scala Spark code in order to parse the fixed width txt file:

```
val schemaDf = df.select(
  df("value").substr(0, 6).cast("integer").alias("id"),
  df("value").substr(7, 6).alias("date"),
  df("value").substr(13, 29).alias("string")
)
```

I'd like to extract the following code:

```
  df("value").substr(0, 6).cast("integer").alias("id"),
  df("value").substr(7, 6).alias("date"),
  df("value").substr(13, 29).alias("string")
```

into the dynamic loop in order to be able to define the column parsing in some external configuration, something like this(where `x` will hold the config for each column parsing but for now this is simple numbers for demo purpose):

```
val x = List(1, 2, 3)
val df1 = df.select(
    x.foreach { 
        df("value").substr(0, 6).cast("integer").alias("id") 
    }
)
```

but right now the following line `df("value").substr(0, 6).cast("integer").alias("id")` don't compile with the following error:

```
type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.sql.Column required: Int ⇒ ?
```

What am I doing wrong and how to properly return the dynamic Column list inside of `df.select` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select` won't take a statement as input, but you can save off the `Columns` you want to create and then expand the expression as input for the `select`:

```
val x = List(1, 2, 3)
val cols: List[Column] = x.map { i =>
  newRecordsDF("value").substr(0, 6).cast("integer").alias("id")
}
val df1 = df.select(cols: _*)
```